# CSS Webkit Animations Not Working in iOS 11

Tags: css, cordova, webkit, ios11, phonegap-build

I have a Cordova/PhoneGap app that has webkit animation that is a flashing dot on the user's location on a map. This works on my older iPhone 5c, and Android, but not on my newer iPad with iOS 11. I'm not sure if I need special settings for iOS 11. Here is the CSS and my HTML meta tag:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes  
       pulse  
      {  
        0%  
        {  
          opacity: 1.0;  
  
  
        }  
        45%  
        {  
          opacity: .20;  
  
  
        }  
        100%  
        {  
          opacity: 1.0;  
  
  
        }  
      }  
     @-moz-keyframes  
       pulse  
      {  
        0%  
        {  
          opacity: 1.0;  
        }  
        45%  
        {  
          opacity: .20;  
  
  
        }  
        100%  
        {  
          opacity: 1.0;  
        }  
      }  
  
  
      #map_graphics_layer {  
  
        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;  
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
        -webkit-animation-name: pulse;  
        -moz-animation-duration: 3s;  
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
        -moz-animation-name: pulse;  
      }  
#map_graphics_layer {  
  
        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;  
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
        -webkit-animation-name: pulse;  
        -moz-animation-duration: 3s;  
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
        -moz-animation-name: pulse;  
      }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui,viewport-fit=cover">
```